# K-gaussian density in pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, kernel-density

I am trying to construct a density of out my data (each tech_dbs[key] is a pandas dataframe) as follows:

```
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
grouped_citing={}
probabilities_citing={}
## Group by distance and calculate probabilities of belonging to the most cited patents for each group of distance
for key,item in tech_dbs.items():
   grouped_citing[key] = tech_dbs[key].groupby('distance_x')
   probabilities_citing[key] = grouped_citing[key].apply(lambda x: gaussian_kde(x['citing_docdb']).integrate_box_1d(np.percentile(x['citing_docdb'], 95), np.inf))
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: `dataset` input should have multiple elements.
```

I have checked and verified that distance_x contains more than one value.
My data look like this:

```
{'docdb_family_id': {0: 569328,
  1: 574660,
  6: 1239098,
  12: 1239622,
  13: 1239624,
  19: 1340471,
  20: 1340485,
  23: 1340508,
  24: 1340519,
  26: 1340647,
  32: 1341170,
  34: 1341188,
  40: 2410050,
  41: 2456718,
  42: 2463680,
  46: 3411930,
  47: 3459918,
  49: 3460123,
  51: 3460351,
  52: 3460409,
  57: 3460812,
  60: 3460972,
  64: 3461002,
  69: 3461088,
  72: 3461172,
  87: 3463716,
  88: 3464855,
  98: 3468888,
  101: 3469272,
  106: 3472873},
 'cited_docdbs': {0: array([26405611., 27079105.,  4321416., 27096884.,  6031690.,  6043910.,
           596005.,  8642629., 26261826., 24750476., 24627241., 22591458.,
          8600475.,  5802640., 13428248., 10455451., 10177065.,  9345445.,
          9203255., 22139349.]),
  1: array([23278096., 22642946., 22437920., 11260528.,  5956195., 27398716.,
         27089078., 27047688., 22181831., 25115774., 25014714., 24355363.,
         24244657., 23458128., 23407037., 25156886.]),
  6: array([25216234., 24916732., 24426379., 24397163., 23845079., 23463145.,
         10417156.,  5777407., 27509152., 25296619., 27054560.]),
  12: array([ 9249538.,  3770167., 27074633., 26158421., 25351735., 25172355.,
         25109266., 23664858., 24951262., 24669345., 24139881., 23586695.,
         23211424., 23074051., 21826650., 21805004., 20340153.]),
  13: array([26673422., 27108903.,  3773931., 24904226., 24863945., 23825854.,
         10400885., 25372210.]),
  19: array([21272262., 21883292., 22392025., 23100861., 25448672., 23827496.,
         24060758., 26918320.,  6285357., 23160290.,  3770297.]),
  20: array([21808322., 26858065., 25401922., 25167492.]),
  23: array([23414619., 23700077., 23916998., 23917011., 23917023., 21923978.,
         24227869.]),
  24: array([22635394., 24392987., 27406148., 27391491., 26671842., 25416705.,
         22248316., 16254362.,  3029629.,  3461742.,  8589904., 10338953.,
         10633369.]),
  26: array([25788386.,  6035376.,  6280238.,  9380485., 10701027., 14217579.,
         19825772., 22089384., 23790326., 24440379., 24914654., 27398924.,
         27398923., 27392998., 25096437., 25351118., 27360051.]),
  32: array([ 9371029., 16739106., 15973703., 16406147., 24635933., 25467964.,
         26540816., 27097342., 14931404., 27284192., 46246738., 27337683.]),
  34: array([12918800., 17261025., 17570830., 17881940., 25356371., 26333781.,
         12918776., 27308577., 12579619., 10564570., 12092936.]),
  40: array([22794937., 23078461., 23612993., 24459220., 24575311., 25227294.,
         26263609.]),
  41: array([22167513., 24032200., 24386230.,  3259455.]),
  42: array([ 5971594., 23977662., 23419588.,  6135585.,  5986602.,  5987710.]),
  46: array([31026202., 28934850., 26464902., 20346443., 16055032., 21692139.,
         23600980., 22670187., 14441561., 14972801., 13183030., 15899938.,
         17637005., 17675565., 22677915., 15124933.]),
  47: array([20376532., 16409642., 11750475., 11307380., 25761545., 25379297.]),
  49: array([25234609., 23189165., 23461883., 25132521.]),
  51: array([20262742., 26267676., 23479915., 22308006., 22038433.]),
  52: array([23899127., 24678427., 26871517., 23081981., 23028155., 22917394.,
         25296094.,  3456862., 23842635., 25020206.]),
  57: array([23437492., 24345719., 25179722., 26202337., 26202338., 26336536.,
         27322866., 26761845., 26902677., 27387578.,  4289386., 23246893.,
         26360272., 22742836., 21950237., 17370315., 17252473., 16606344.,
         16545089., 10533978., 10127509.,  5885216.,  9462140.,  9432294.,
          7909952.,  5922833., 22124778.]),
  60: array([24891883., 26065901., 24468237., 24066303., 22808616., 22208632.,
          8148875., 12030629.]),
  64: array([27283885., 24253315., 24175383., 22343315.,  6334058., 26870720.]),
  69: array([27527982., 25248043., 10712462., 21765350., 25179712.]),
  72: array([25365252., 40028880., 27097939., 26649403., 25476452., 24564660.,
         26511922., 22570199., 24558472.,  8538373., 21749852., 22562419.]),
  87: array([24031416.,  3306247., 25560751., 22917393., 23581745.]),
  88: array([ 3371283., 25384890., 25143217., 24084406., 23990165., 23677931.,
         23018571.,  9659549.,  9601625., 24758795.]),
  98: array([ 2440437., 24797252., 23651239., 23301571., 22656725., 21766159.,
          9327981.,  7725676.,  7576129.,  2981902.,  2284813.]),
  101: array([24598706., 24917978., 27065088.]),
  106: array([27286477., 27299989., 27294233., 27211100., 27181923., 26865889.,
         14133493., 23791357., 11463023., 10451029., 10227124.,  5741820.,
          4215816., 12353096.])},
 'cpc_tech': {0: 'Y10S',
  1: 'Y10S',
  6: 'Y10S',
  12: 'Y10S',
  13: 'Y10S',
  19: 'Y10S',
  20: 'Y10S',
  23: 'Y10S',
  24: 'Y10S',
  26: 'Y10S',
  32: 'Y10S',
  34: 'Y10S',
  40: 'Y10S',
  41: 'Y10S',
  42: 'Y10S',
  46: 'Y10S',
  47: 'Y10S',
  49: 'Y10S',
  51: 'Y10S',
  52: 'Y10S',
  57: 'Y10S',
  60: 'Y10S',
  64: 'Y10S',
  69: 'Y10S',
  72: 'Y10S',
  87: 'Y10S',
  88: 'Y10S',
  98: 'Y10S',
  101: 'Y10S',
  106: 'Y10S'},
 'year': {0: 1981,
  1: 1987,
  6: 1992,
  12: 1990,
  13: 1992,
  19: 1993,
  20: 1993,
  23: 1993,
  24: 1993,
  26: 1994,
  32: 1996,
  34: 1996,
  40: 1972,
  41: 1972,
  42: 1993,
  46: 1993,
  47: 1998,
  49: 1972,
  51: 1972,
  52: 1972,
  57: 2001,
  60: 1998,
  64: 1998,
  69: 1999,
  72: 2000,
  87: 1973,
  88: 1974,
  98: 1976,
  101: 1976,
  106: 1979},
 'nr_cited': {0: 20,
  1: 16,
  6: 11,
  12: 17,
  13: 8,
  19: 11,
  20: 4,
  23: 7,
  24: 13,
  26: 17,
  32: 12,
  34: 11,
  40: 7,
  41: 4,
  42: 6,
  46: 16,
  47: 6,
  49: 4,
  51: 5,
  52: 10,
  57: 27,
  60: 8,
  64: 6,
  69: 5,
  72: 12,
  87: 5,
  88: 10,
  98: 11,
  101: 3,
  106: 14},
 'fronteer_x': {0: 0,
  1: 0,
  6: 0,
  12: 0,
  13: 0,
  19: 0,
  20: 0,
  23: 0,
  24: 0,
  26: 0,
  32: 0,
  34: 0,
  40: 0,
  41: 0,
  42: 0,
  46: 0,
  47: 0,
  49: 0,
  51: 0,
  52: 0,
  57: 0,
  60: 0,
  64: 0,
  69: 0,
  72: 0,
  87: 0,
  88: 0,
  98: 0,
  101: 0,
  106: 0},
 'distance_x': {0: inf,
  1: inf,
  6: inf,
  12: inf,
  13: inf,
  19: inf,
  20: inf,
  23: inf,
  24: inf,
  26: inf,
  32: inf,
  34: 4.0,
  40: inf,
  41: inf,
  42: inf,
  46: inf,
  47: inf,
  49: inf,
  51: inf,
  52: inf,
  57: 1.0,
  60: inf,
  64: inf,
  69: 2.0,
  72: inf,
  87: inf,
  88: inf,
  98: inf,
  101: inf,
  106: inf},
 'citing_docdb': {0: 10,
  1: 21,
  6: 31,
  12: 12,
  13: 9,
  19: 17,
  20: 5,
  23: 16,
  24: 12,
  26: 1,
  32: 1,
  34: 25,
  40: 20,
  41: 1,
  42: 1,
  46: 4,
  47: 12,
  49: 4,
  51: 2,
  52: 5,
  57: 8,
  60: 1,
  64: 2,
  69: 9,
  72: 3,
  87: 5,
  88: 2,
  98: 3,
  101: 12,
  106: 8},
 'fronteer_y': {0: 0,
  1: 0,
  6: 0,
  12: 0,
  13: 0,
  19: 0,
  20: 0,
  23: 0,
  24: 0,
  26: 0,
  32: 0,
  34: 0,
  40: 0,
  41: 0,
  42: 0,
  46: 0,
  47: 0,
  49: 0,
  51: 0,
  52: 0,
  57: 0,
  60: 0,
  64: 0,
  69: 0,
  72: 0,
  87: 0,
  88: 0,
  98: 0,
  101: 0,
  106: 0},
 'distance_y': {0: inf,
  1: inf,
  6: inf,
  12: inf,
  13: inf,
  19: inf,
  20: inf,
  23: inf,
  24: inf,
  26: inf,
  32: inf,
  34: 4.0,
  40: inf,
  41: inf,
  42: inf,
  46: inf,
  47: inf,
  49: inf,
  51: inf,
  52: inf,
  57: 1.0,
  60: inf,
  64: inf,
  69: 2.0,
  72: inf,
  87: inf,
  88: inf,
  98: inf,
  101: inf,
  106: inf}}
```

What's wrong? I know that ValueError: `dataset` input should have multiple elements.
may be due to the fact that the function kde requires that there are multiple elements provided. But I checked it and I do not know what is going wrong. With the overall database (not split into chunks into a dictionary) everything worked smoothly!

Thank you in advance